# jquery how to remove a column from a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to click in a Close img, and remove all the column where the img is located.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
            var colnum = $(this).closest("td").prevAll("td").html();

    $(this).closest("table").find("tr td:eq(" + colnum + ")").remove();
```

but, its not working.

**EDIT: GUYS, SORRY FOR THE FIRST POST, I WAS KIND A HURRY TO OPEN THE QUESTION.
I EDIT EVERYTHING. TAKE A LOOK IN THE DEMO**

the html demo: [New Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TdCYy/33/)

if you guys see the red stuffs in the table, that I need to remove when click que "CLOSE". 
Remove the column where I'm clicking.

ps.: guys, the red class was just to you guys see where need to be the close event.

Comment: Nested Tables? Ouch. This would be a lot easier if you weren't removing columns of nested columns.

Comment: There are a lot of errors in the code, the handler `)}` should end in `});`.  Also HTML attributes should be wrapped in double quotes `"` instead of single quotes.  Also, the colnum variable you are assigning isn't getting the column number.  Use `$(this).index();` instead.  Using tables isn't a bad thing if you are displaying tabular data but I'm not sure nested tables are appropriate and removing columns completely is kind of a code smell as well... I don't have any truly helpful advice rather than start fixing all your errors first before moving forward on this one.

Comment: John Strickler: sry , i "paste" the code in jsfiddle missing somthing's . in my source its ok.

Comment: The html its ok now, i edit all the stuffs in the demo, please, take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example demo, what should actually close?...  I modified it slightly and the close column disappears, but I am unsure what else you are expecting to be removed.

See here:  http://jsfiddle.net/gfosco/TdCYy/24/

The issue is being inside a nested table... You want to remove the column from the cell parent tables parent table.

Updated example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/gfosco/TdCYy/37/

Comment: The html its ok now, i edit all the stuffs in the demo, please, take a look

Comment: @ric_bfa Updated example to working order... The issue is being 2 tables deep.  Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: @Fosco: yes, its work, but the numbers of columms is dinamic, i have a input, in the input i put how many columms will appear, and each columm i add a close buttom, to remove the columm that just has beem add, exp: http://jsfiddle.net/5AFJn/19/ i can have alost of columms.

Comment: @ric_bfa you switched to ID's and you can't have 2 elements with the same ID..   It works fine with multiple columns using a class selector:  http://jsfiddle.net/gfosco/5AFJn/20/

Comment: @Fosco: edit, was ID , change to class. take a look http://jsfiddle.net/5AFJn/22/

Comment: @Fosco: yes, just got that. will check.

Comment: @ric_bfa why did you update the `var idx` to +2?  It should stay +1 always.. it's to switch from a 0 based index to a 1 based index.

Comment: @Fosco: i was just testing, beacause in the my official code, one of the columms its not beeing removed. dont know why

Comment: @ric_bfa well if you can post relevant code I can look, but you can see that I've provided a valid solution to your request.

Comment: @Fosco: yes, check this out, i was just organazing all the stuffs http://jsfiddle.net/QpuT5/17/

Comment: @ric_bfa it's due to all of the crazy colspan action you have going on... I really don't know if I'm up for digging through all of it to find a perfect solution.  There's a better way to manage these column headers, maybe I'll work on that instead...

Comment: @ric_bfa check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/gfosco/QpuT5/21/  Since the rows AFTER the header row had multiple columns, I first remove the right column from all rows after row #1, then do the previous remove.

Comment: @Fosco: perfect man, congratulation! will try to clean this html crazy stuffs. thnks again!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the nth-child selector to get the cells in nth column, something like this:

```
$(this).closest("table").find("tr td:nth-child(" + colnum + ")").remove();
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out this link, I have edited your demo http://jsfiddle.net/TdCYy/39/

This is the HTML unchanged, except for the class first-row added to the first red row:

```
<table border='1' width='100%'>
    <tr>
        <td>Somthing 1</td>
        <td>Somthing 2</td>
        <td>Somthing 3</td>
        <td>
            <table border='1' style='border: solid red;' width='100%'>
                <tr class="first-row">
                    <td colspan='2'>
                        Something
                        <span style='float: right' class='img_romove_columm'>Close</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Another</td>
                    <td>Another 1</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Result</td>
        <td>Result</td>
        <td>Result</td>
        <td class='red'>Result</td>                    
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Result</td>
        <td>Result</td>
        <td>Result</td>
        <td class='red'>Result</td>                    
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Result</td>
        <td>Result</td>
        <td>Result</td>
        <td class='red'>Result</td>            
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Result</td>
        <td>Result</td>
        <td>Result</td>            
        <td class='red'>Result</td>   
    </tr>            
</table>
```

CSS is untouched.

Javascript should be (this works):

```
$(".img_romove_columm").click(function(){
    // Hide the first row that has the close button, and also hide the row right after it (another, another1)
    $('tr.first-row, tr.first-row + tr').hide();
    // Hide everything that has the red class (result, result, result, result, )
    $('td.red').hide();
});
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: forget the class "red", was just to see where the event click will rappend, my problem is, i need to close all the columm without any class or id especification

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example I came up with. simply apply the same class (`red`) to all of the elements to want to disappear, including the nested table. Then you can call

```
    $('.red').hide();
```

**FIDDLE** http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/TdCYy/42/

Comment: the red class that i put in the demo was just to see where the click event will apperar :)

Comment: Yes, I know. It can be any class. It can even be a class that's not in your CSS. It's just to identify a group of objects that you want to appear. `red` can just as easily be `closable` or anything else. On a side note, don't expect to get a lot of help if you go around down-voting every answer that's not exactly what you want. Two of us on this page gave you two working examples, and because they have the word `red` in them, they were downvoted. Nowhere in your question did you specify that this had to be done without classes. I am down-voting your question, since it was not properly asked.